# Jquery ajax post removing some char in response

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I am sending a long string  via ajax post and trying to save it in database. Everything is working fine but it's missing some char like '+' in response.

Why this happening and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Show your code. You probably need to escape with `encodeURIComponent` (or with a built in jQuery method that encodes for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are URL components like '+','&' .You should encode them before post.

Try to encode using `encodeURIComponent(Value)`

Read here for more details : [**JavaScript encodeURIComponent() Escapes "+" Symbol**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/564-JavaScript-encodeURIComponent-Escapes-Symbol.htm)